# Job running at application startup and shouldn't

Tags: android, android-job

I have an android-job from the Evernote lib. The job is set to run periodically on certain circumstances. So the job build is only called when I want to start a job periodically (which is not at the beginning of my app)

**Create a JobService:**

```
class JobService : Job() {

    companion object {

        private var jobId = 0

        fun scheduleJobPeriodically(ms: Long) {
            if (jobRequested()) {
                cancelJob()
            }
            jobId = JobRequest.Builder("JOB_TAG")
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .setPeriodic(ms, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                    .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
                    .build()
                    .schedule()
        }

        fun cancelJob() {
            JobManager.instance().cancel(jobId)
        }

    }

    override fun onRunJob(params: Params): Result {
        Timber.d(">>>>>>>>>>>Job is Running")
        Result.SUCCESS
    }
}
```

**A JobCreator:**

```
class MyJobCreator : JobCreator {
  override fun create(tag: String): Job? {
    return when (tag) {
        "JOB_TAG" -> {
            JobService()
        }
        else -> null
    }
 }
}
```

In **application class** add the required line to register the job:

```
JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(MyJobCreator())
```

At this point the application is started and the JobService class is created. (OK)
But in this class, there is this method **scheduleJobPeriodically**, and this method is fired and it shouldn't, because I don't explicitly start it.
I have started my app in debug mode and I am sure that the periodic creation is not called directly, as well as the JobRequestBuilder that set the tag for a job. But the code in the **onRunJob** is fired and it's the issue.

Thank in advance.